# Why while defining String in java, being a class, we do not use new?

Tags: java, string, class

Why while defining String in java, being a class, we do not use new keyword?

We use it as:

```
String a="Hello";
```

Classes in Java are defined as:

```
Class1 obj = new Class1;
```

Answer (score 0):

String constansts are automatically turned into String objects.