# String objects which are not literal not requiring new keyword?

Tags: java, string, new-operator

So I know there are other similar questions to this, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192233/why-while-defining-string-in-java-being-a-class-we-do-not-use-new?lq=1) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680344/why-new-keyword-not-needed-for-string). But Their answer seems to be that because they are literal and part of some pool of immutable literal constants, they will remain available. This sort of makes sense to me, but then why do non literals also work fine? When do I ever have to use the "new" keyword when dealing with strings. In the example below, I use strings to do a few things, but everything works fine and I never use the "new" keyword (correction: I never use it with a String type object).

```
import java.util.*;

class teststrings{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String nonew;
      String nonew2;
      String literally= "old";
      literally= "new"; //does the word "old" get garbage collected here?
      nonew = in.nextLine(); //this does not use the new keyword, but it works, why?
      System.out.println("nonew:"+nonew);
      System.out.println("literally:"+literally);
      nonew2 = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("nonew:"+nonew); //the data is still preserved here
      System.out.println("nonew2:"+nonew2);
      //I didn't use the new keyword at all, but everything worked
      //So, when do I need to use it?
   }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to do some more reading.  The `new` keyword is used inside `nextLine()`.  You are just getting passed the reference to it as a return value.

Comment: "I didn't use the new keyword at all" No, you used the `new` keyword in `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: Thanks Mike, that was very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:
"Does the word "old" get garbage collected here?"
Chances are your compiler realises it's never used and just skips it altogether.

`Scanner::nextLine` returns a `String`, and the value returned by the method is used for the assignment.

As for when *to* use `new` for `String`s...  Well, rarely would probably be best.  The only time I've ever seen it used would be for internal constants.  For example

```
public class MatchChecker {
    private static final String ANY_VALUE = new String("*");

    private final Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<Object, String>();

    public void addMatch(Object object, String string) {
        map.put(object, string);
    }

    public void addAnyValueMatch(Object object) {
        map.put(object, ANY_VALUE);
    }

    public boolean matches(Object object, String string) {
        if (!map.contains(object)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map.get(object) == ANY_VALUE || map.get(object).equals(string)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which would mean *only* those Objects added via `addAnyValueMatch` would match any value (as it's tested with `==`), even if the user used `"*"` as the string in `addMatch`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and an example of a special use case in which it would be used, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are treated specially in Java. The Java JVM makes use of a cache like implementation called a String pool.

Unlike other objects, when you create a literal String like this: `String mystring = "Hello";` Java will first check to see if the String "Hello" already exists in the String pool. If not, it will add it to be cached and reused if referenced again.

So, when you assign a variable to "Hello" the first time, it gets added to the pool:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
String s3 = s1;
s1 = "SomethingElse"
```

In the code above, when s1 is assigned "Hello" the JVM will see it is not stored in the pool and create/add it to the pool.
For s2, you are again referencing "Hello". The JVM will see it in the pool and assign s2 to the same String stored in the pool. s3 is simply assigned to the value referenced at the memory address of s1, or the same string "Hello". Finally, s1 is then reassigned to another String, which doesn't exist yet in the pool, so is added. Also, s1 no longer points to "Hello", yet it will not be garbage collected, for two reasons. 1:t is being stored in the String pool and 2: s2 also points to the same referenced string.

With Strings, you should never use the `new` keyword for creating literal strings. If you do, you are not taking advantage of the String pool reuse and could cause multiple instances of the same String to exist in memory, which is a waste.

Comment: There are legitimate uses `new` with `String ` such as constructing one from a byte array: `new String(someByteArray) `.

Comment: Fair enough, updated the answer to clarify that you shouldn't use new for literal strings. Thanks for pointing that out.